# Molecular add on option not showing in particles tab in Blender 4.0

Tags: particles

Anyone knows why the molecular add on is not showing as an option in my Particles Tab?

Pic below is the Tut I am following.. and he has the molecular option visible in the particles tab..

[image]

And here is my particles tab without the molecular option there.. any one knows why it is missing in my blender? I am using 4.0, did the location op the molecular specs changed for Blender 4.0?

[image]

Is it because things have moved for the Molecular add on in Blender 4.0? Or am I doint something wrong? I followed all the steps of the tutorial, and ofc I've got the add on installed. Thnx.

Comment: Has it been updated to be compatible with the version 4 APIs?

Comment: Yea It has moved idd. Thnx for your reply.